# Hacked Ethereum wallet -- What do do with staked tokens?

Tags: metamask, wallets, security

My MetaMask wallet was unfortunately hacked and the hacker drained all of my tokens. I've sent some test tokens back to the wallet to check if the hacker had installed a smart contract to automatically remove any tokens but that doesn't seem to be the case. The test tokens are still there.

I have some tokens staked from that address and I'm very worried that when I unstake them and withdraw them to the compromised address, the hacker will take the tokens. Is there any way to circumvent this? For example, could I implement a whitelist so that the unstaked tokens can only be sent to a pre-approved address?

Thanks for your help.

JK

Comment: The latest weekinethereumnews.com has a story about a succesful attempt to rescue tokens from a compromised account using flashbots. Read the whole ordeal https://twitter.com/smpalladino/status/1373048978443472897.

Comment: Thanks Ismael. I've contacted the author of that tweet.

Comment: Any update on the situation? My Trust Wallet was compromised too. I'm in the same boat worried about my staked BNB and CAKE.

Answer (score 0):

It is about 9 months since this question was asked, but for new sweeper bots victims, I created this repo https://github.com/eniolasonowo/CompromisedWalletTokenRescue, to help victims rescue their funds/assets (Tokens, Stakes, NFTs) from compromised wallets.